# discord.py How to save permissions of a channel and use them on another channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

I try to save the permissions of a voicechannel in a json file and grab it again to use them on another voicechannel. I think I'm on the right way, but I don't know what to do next:

```
@bot.command()
async def channel(ctx):
  tempc = ctx.author.voice.channel
  for useroverwrite in tempc.overwrites:
    useroverwriteperms = tempc.overwrites_for(useroverwrite)
    useroverwritepair = useroverwriteperms.pair()

    firstvalue = useroverwritepair[0].value
    secondvalue = useroverwritepair[1].value
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Maybe use a category and sync all the perms in that?

Comment: The problem is, there can be multiple users who use that command.

Comment: Add a brief description on what do you want to accomplish with this command. There might be an easier way to do it.

Comment: I want to do a tempchannel bot. And you should safe the channel settings of the channel you're in. Then you can select that saved channel settings and if you creating a channel again the saved channel settings should be applied on the new channel.